# Some test runs give it to me concurrent exception with selenium TestNg, How to do fix this?

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, testng, java.util.concurrent

When i run my test cases with cucumber textNg on jenkins with maven not always bu sometimes it give it error `java.util.concurrent.Ex.` Can you help me? Some of my methods are synchronized so can it be? I need to use synchronized for my methods to work properly.

This my  testNg xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "https://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Suite" data-provider-thread-count="8"
    thread-count="1" parallel="tests">
    <listeners>
        <listener
            class-name="com.oneapi.ta.oneapihub.listeners.TestNGListener" />
    </listeners>

    <test name="Firefox">
        <parameter name="browser" value="firefox"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.oneapi.ta.oneapihub.runners.OneApiHubTestAutomationRunnerTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    
    <test name="Chrome">
        <parameter name="browser" value="chrome"></parameter>
        <classes>
            <class
                name="com.oneapi.ta.oneapihub.runners.OneApiHubTestAutomationRunnerTest" />
        </classes>
    </test>
    
<!--    <test name="Edge"> -->
<!--        <parameter name="browser" value="edge"></parameter> -->
<!--        <classes> -->
<!--            <class -->
<!--                name="com.oneapi.ta.oneapihub.runners.OneApiHubTestAutomationRunnerTest" /> -->
<!--        </classes> -->
<!--    </test> -->


<!--    <test name="Safari"> -->
<!--        <parameter name="browser" value="safari"></parameter> -->
<!--        <classes> -->
<!--            <class -->
<!--                name="com.oneapi.ta.oneapihub.runners.OneApiHubTestAutomationRunnerTest" /> -->
<!--        </classes> -->
<!--    </test> -->
</suite>
```

This is my runnerClass

```
@BeforeClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void setUpClass() throws Exception {
    
        testNGCucumberRunner = new TestNGCucumberRunner(this.getClass());
    }

    @Parameters({ "browser" })
    @BeforeMethod
    public static void launchBrowser(String browser) throws Throwable {
        DriverManager.testNgBrowserParameter = browser;
    }

    @Test(dataProvider = "scenarios")
    public void runScenario(PickleWrapper pickleWrapper, FeatureWrapper featureWrapper, ITestContext iTestContext)
            throws Throwable {
        
        String browser = iTestContext.getCurrentXmlTest().getLocalParameters().get("browser");

        System.out.println("Running Test on Browser:" + browser + " Thread ID:" + Thread.currentThread().getId());
        if (ExtentReportManager.getFeature(featureWrapper.toString()) == null) {
            ExtentReportManager.startFeature(featureWrapper.toString());
            ExtentReportManager.startScenario(featureWrapper.toString(), pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
            ExtentReportManager.getScenario().assignCategory(browser);

        } else {
            ExtentReportManager.startScenario(featureWrapper.toString(), pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
            ExtentReportManager.getScenario().assignCategory(browser);
        }
        DriverManager.setScenarioName(pickleWrapper.getPickle().getName());
        DriverManager.setFeatureName(featureWrapper.toString().replace("\"", ""));
        DriverManager.setTagName(pickleWrapper.getPickle().getTags().toString().replaceAll("([^a-zA-Z\\s])", ""));
        testNGCucumberRunner.runScenario(pickleWrapper.getPickle());
    }

    @DataProvider(parallel = true)
    public Object[][] scenarios() {
        return testNGCucumberRunner.provideScenarios();
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public static void closeBrowser() {
        DriverManager.stopDriver();
        ExtentReportManager.flushExtentReport();
        DriverManager.removeFinishedMap();
    }

    @AfterClass(alwaysRun = true)
    public void tearDownClass() throws Exception {
        testNGCucumberRunner.finish(); The error is this line.
        //SendEmail.sendTestResaultWithEmail();
    }
```

This is DriverManager

`initializeDriver` is my create driver method.

```
private static Map<Integer, WebDriver> webDriverMap = new HashMap<Integer, WebDriver>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> browserMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> scenarioNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> featureNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    private static Map<Integer, String> tagNameMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    public static Map<String, String> scenarioSteps = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public String getBrowser () {
        
        return browserMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    public static WebDriver getDriver() {

        return (WebDriver) webDriverMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }

    public static synchronized void startDriver(String browser, String scenarioName) throws Throwable {
        
        webDriverMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), initializeDriver(browser, scenarioName));
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setScenarioName(String scenarioName) throws Throwable {
        
        scenarioNameMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), scenarioName);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getScenarioName() throws Throwable {
        
        return scenarioNameMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setFeatureName(String featureName) throws Throwable {
        
        featureNameMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), featureName);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getFeatureName() throws Throwable {
        
        return featureNameMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setTagName(String tagName) throws Throwable {
        
        tagNameMap.put((int)Thread.currentThread().getId(), tagName);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getTagName() throws Throwable {
        
        return tagNameMap.get((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
    public static synchronized void setScenarioSteps(String scenario, String steps) throws Throwable {

        scenarioSteps.put(scenario, steps);
    }
    
    public static synchronized String getScenarioSteps(String scenario) throws Throwable {
        
        return scenarioSteps.get(scenario);
    }
    
    public static synchronized void removeFinishedMap() {
        
        webDriverMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        scenarioNameMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        browserMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        featureNameMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
        tagNameMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
    
public static void stopDriver() {
         getDriver().quit();
         webDriverMap.remove((int)Thread.currentThread().getId());
    }
```

Comment: It might be worth considering using `ThreadLocal` instead of thread id-keyed maps.

Answer (score 0):

```
public String getBrowser () {
public static WebDriver getDriver() {
public static void stopDriver() {
```

These methods are not synchronized. This allows concurrent modification of the webdriver map and the other maps.

You should make these methods synchronized. Or consider using a `ThreadLocal` instead of a map as you are attempting to reimplement the same semantics.

Comment: Hi, @M.P. Korstanje, how can i you ThreadLocal? is it like that? "ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver> driver = new ThreadLocal<>();"